# How to resize html2canvas and scale to original 100% resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html2canvas

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.querySelector(".canvas-layout").appendChild(canvas);
});
```

I need to resize this canvas (2304x1440 pixels to 230.4x144, for example) and scale back to the original 100% (2304x1440). How can I do that?

I use it for blur-effect on a background of the fixed header. Then scroll it with `$(this).scrollTop();` The method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091627/how-to-create-background-blur-on-the-fixed-header).

Comment: Hi, Try by using css `transform` property where you can scale in and scale out , You have not mentioned which event you need to resize
`transform: scale(1);` for 100% and 'transform: scale(0.1);' for 10%

Comment: @Sethuraman transform only changes the view. Not a resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get the canvas object from the html2canvas method, use its context to draw the canvas again in your desired resolution.

Like this for example,

```
function resizeCanvas(canvas, newHeight, newWidth)
{
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        newCanvas.height = canvas.height;
        newCanvas.width = canvas.width;
        newCanvas.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        return newCanvas;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: This code is wrong, you need a new context like `const newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d')` because `putImageData` is a method of the context, not the canvas!